# TFS Everywhere - Branching best practices

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Can someone point me to good documentation or tutorials to perform branching using TFS everywhere. Coming from a SVN background it is quite confusing to understand TFS branching. I would like to do in place switch to branches like SVN. I originally thought the Switch to Branch option available in the team context menu works like SVN switch to branch. But it doesnt seem to do anything. 
Any pointers would be very helpful.

Javid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/

Is a superb guide to Branching and Merging strategies in TFS.

And here are some more branching examples although the ALM guide contains some as well.

https://intovsts.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/techdays2010_branchingandmergingwithtfs2010.pdf

As to SVN switch to branch, you might be looking for the Convert folder to branch feature.

Hope this helps.